# MongoDB Compass $match and $text results in "Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found."

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Doing a simple $match aggregation results in the `Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found.` error.

```
{
  $text: {
    $search: "search query"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a very frustrating error that I hope they address soon.

Comment: did you get answer?

Comment: please provide your search query.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same error, but in my case I use `$addFields` with `$switch` statement and here `$regexMatch` breaks my pipeline in the Compass:

```
{
  attribute: {
    $switch: {
      branches: [
        {
          case: {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: "$attribute",
              regex: /expression/
            }
          },
          then: "..."
        }
      ],
      default: "$attribute"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I execute it in the CLI it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

Try This query for Search,

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
       {
        $match:{
             "Field_name":
                {
                   $regex:'Search_value',
                   $options: "si" 
                 }
 }}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use $text, you need to create a text index. Let's consider that you have a collection named `countries` and text field named `capital`. You can create a text index by the command `db.countries.createIndex({capital:"text"})`.

Now, you can aggregate and use $text in the following manner. Note the square brackets in which we enclose the operations.

```
db.countries.aggregate([
    {
      $match:{
        $text: {
          $search: "Mumbai"
        }
      }
    }
])
```

Answer (score -1):

You are expected to provide a query object directly in the text box.

Example

```
/**
 * query - The query in MQL.
 */
{
  count_field: {"$gt": 1}
}
```